# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '' does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I'm using Django 1.9 and DRF 3.9.2 for my project and I'm getting this error

*django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.*

Here's my project folder structure

```
webhooksub/
 |-- slack/
 |    |-- rest_slack/                
 |    |    |-- migrations/
 |    |    |    +-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- admin.py
 |    |    |-- apps.py
 |    |    |-- models.py
 |    |    |-- tests.py
 |    |    |-- urls.py
 |    |    +-- views.py
 |    |-- slack/
 |    |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |    |-- settings.py
 |    |    |-- urls.py
 |    |    |-- wsgi.py
 |    +-- manage.py
 +-- venv/
```

Here is my slack/urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include('slack.rest_slack.urls', namespace='rest_slack')),
]
```

and rest_slack/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_slack.views import DRSEventView, DRSCommandView

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'web', DRSEventView)
router.register(r'events', DRSCommandView)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Can someone tell me what is it I'm doing wrong and what changes I can do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your directory structure above, I think there's a problem with including the `rest_slack` urls.

Instead of:

```
url(r'^api/', include('slack.rest_slack.urls', namespace='rest_slack')),
```

I think it should be:

```
url(r'^api/', include('rest_slack.urls', namespace='rest_slack')),
```

Notice that there's no need for the `slack` part in `slack.rest_slack.urls`.